# Why does macOS kept auto correcting z to s?

Tags: mac, keyboard, high-sierra

I'm not sure where in the settings I changed accidentally but now wherever I type, in browser, note, or emails etc, my **s** always gets auto corrected to a **z**. For instance, when I type **quantization**, the word gets auto-corrected to **quantisation**. I have to scroll back to change that s back to z each and every time. It's really annoying.

Comment: Is your spellcheck set to British English by some chance?

Comment: Please also add info regarding the kind of apple device you are talking about and the apps where this happens.

Comment: There are 7 english settings known by Apple. Which is the one you use in everydays life?

Comment: It looks like it's correcting your incorrect American spellings to the correct British spellings. Congratulations! Now get yourself some tea and crumpets and you can learn how to pronounce vase properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure where in the settings I changed accidentally but now wherever I type, in browser, note, or emails etc, my s always gets auto corrected to a z.

Assuming you are on a **Mac**, go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text** > **Spelling:** and either select the language you are using or set it to the default, **Automatic by Language**.

Note that you may also want to check what you have set, or if you changed from the default settings, from the **Set Up…** *pop-up menu item* after clicking **Automatic by Language** *pop-up*. If you have not modified anything in the **Set Up…** from the installed defaults you should not hav an issue with using **Automatic by Language**. This of course is assuming that **U.S. English** was your original language of choice and not **British English** which uses **s** in places where **U.S. English** uses **z** in those instances it's being auto-corrected.

---

[image]

On a default **U.S. English** install, this is what the *sheet* from the **Set Up…** *pop-up menu item* looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apple's (and other) British English spellchecker favours -ise endings instead of -ize, for some reason**. It sounds like you've got British English selected.

***(Interestingly, -ise in British English is a recent development, and the Oxford English Dictionary still gives -ize for most words as the preferred spelling.)*

Comment: Recent? are you sure? see https://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/criticizing-ize-and-ise

Comment: @SolarMike: Yes. There's an episode of Inspector Morse in the 1980s where he determines a suicide note to be fake because "No Oxford man would spell realize with an S." I was taught that most words can be spelled with a Z but some must never be (as listed in your cited article): and it is this rule that drove people to err on the side of caution, in the 90s, just a spellcheckers became  a thing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling